# bash/awk: Getting largest value per cell

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a tab-separated fileA that looks like this:

```
seqnameAa_len_240                     seqnameBa_len_247
seqnameAb_len_881                     seqnameBb_len_719
seqnameAc_len_736,seqnameAd_len_640   seqnameBc_len_489
seqnameAe_len_241                     seqnameBd_len_302,seqnameBe_len_465
seqnameAf_len_436,seqnameAf_len_620   seqnameBf_len_452,seqnameBg_len_435
```

Sequences on the left are from one dataset and sequences from the right are from another. Each row reflects one group of similar sequences. In some cases, there are more than one sequence from one, the other or both datasets that belong to the same sequence group (reflected by several sequences delineated by commas in one column).

For each row, I would like to find a way to find the largest value for each of the two datasets giving the following output.

```
240    247
881    719
736    489
241    465
620    452
```

I thought about make a for loop over all the rows, and then for each row replace comma with a newline, then remove all the text and just keep the numbers and select the largest value per column with awk. But with my current bash/awk knowledge that would have to be done column-wise, and there is not a set number of comma-separated entries per cell and I am not sure how to do that.

Is there a simpler way of getting the above output from fileA?

Comment: Do not hesitate to try and code it yourself and show your attempts. Otherwise it is very likely that you will get used to get things done and by the time you need yourself to do them, you won't have learned anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
        split($fldNr,fldArr,/,/)
        for (sfNr=1; sfNr in fldArr; sfNr++) {
            sub(/.*_/,"",fldArr[sfNr])
            max = ( (sfNr==1)||(fldArr[sfNr]>max) ? fldArr[sfNr] : max)
        }
        $fldNr = max
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
240     247
881     719
736     489
241     465
620     452
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -MList::Util=max -lane '
    print max($F[0] =~ /\d+/g), "\t", max($F[1] =~ /\d+/g)
' fileA
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some gawk trickery to achieve this without manual splitting:

```
gawk -F , -v RS='[\t\n]' '{ m = 0; for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { sub(/.*_/, "", $i); if($i > m) { m = $i } } printf m RT }'
```

The trick is to use tabs and newlines as record separators, so that a record is no longer a line but what would otherwise be a field (such as `seqnameAf_len_436,seqnameAf_len_620`), and the fields `$1`, `$2` and so forth are the comma-delimited subfields (because of `-F ,`). Then

```
{
  m = 0
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { # walk through the (comma-delimited) fields 
    sub(/.*_/, "", $i)       # isolate the number
    if($i > m) {             # find the maximum
      m = $i
    }
  }
  printf m RT                # and print it with the same record terminator
                             # that was in the input (tab or newline)
}
```

Both the use of regexes as record separator and `RT` are gawk-specific.